# What diffence between use and don't use function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have seen an issue when I try to create a function for concatenating string, and the program have built successfully with no compile time error, but when it run, my program have crashed. However, when I write the code directly into `int main()`, the program have run smoothly without error.
Is there any one can explain?

The code that causes program crash is:

```
...
inline char *concatStr(char *target, char *source){
  return copyStr(_endOfStr(source), source);
}
int main(){
  char hello[MAX] = "Hello ";
  char world[MAX] = "World!!\n";
  concatStr(hello, world); //create "Hello World!!\n" by adding "World!!\n" to end of "Hello "
  cout << hello; //I want display "Hello World!!"
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The replacement code is:

```
...
int main(){
  char hello[MAX] = "Hello ";
  char world[MAX] = "World!!\n";
  copyStr(_endOfStr(hello), world);
  cout << hello;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

function `char *copyStr(char *target, char *source)` overwiting `target` and returning pointer which point to `null` in target

function `char *_endOfStr(char *str)` returning pointer which point to null in `str`

Comment: You should _probably_ be using `std::string`: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=829

Comment: There's no obvious reason why those two snippets should give different behaviour, unless the code you haven't shown us (like the implementation of `copyStr` and  `_endOfStr`) causes undefined behaviour, or `MAX` isn't large enough for the result. In any case use `std::string` and avoid all this dangerous messing around with fixed arrays.

Comment: MAX = 255 in my code

Comment: `_endOfStr` may be using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on your crashing code:

```
return copyStr(_endOfStr(source), source);
```

should be

```
return copyStr(_endOfStr(target), source);
```

I don't have a C++ compiler at hand right now, but that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice, may be that's a bad question

Answer (score -1):

Since you use c++, instead of C, use string instead of char*.

Your code should look sometjing like this:

```
#include <string>
...
int main(){
  std::string hello = "Hello ";
  std::string world = "World!!\n";
  std::string helloWorld = hello + world;
  cout << helloWorld;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: but I really want why the first crash althought the second one smoothly

Comment: This is just printing "Hello "